# youtube-dl setting options in python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am trying to save livestreams using youtube-dl API in python with the following code. Since it's a continuous live stream there is no end to the video, so I am using `hls-use-mpegts` as a way to periodically read the video for processing, that flag makes `.mp4.part` files playable.

Although the `hls-use-mpegts` option works well with the command-line thus:

`youtube-dl -f worst <some URL> --retries infinite --continue --hls-use-mpegts`

it doesn't seem to work with this code. I don't see any errors but don't see the file being saved in mpegts format. Do I have the options setting correct?

```
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'worst',
        'retries': 99,
        'continue': True,
        'hls-use-mpegts': True
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
```

Comment: Try using `hls_use_mpegts` for options instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because (sorry for saying that) the docs is somewhat good&shitt* at the same time.
I found every switches/cli-options that you were to use within Python you have to replace *-* (**dash**) to *_* (**sub dash**).

## Solution

In your case, **hls_use_mpegts** is the solution.

## Why?

Read/explore about that here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/5208ae92fc3e2916cdccae45c6b9a516be3d5796/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py#L50
and
here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/5208ae92fc3e2916cdccae45c6b9a516be3d5796/youtube_dl/__init__.py#L428

or just browse as I do usually for those inconveniences: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/search?q=hls_use_mpegts%3A (fortunately GitHub does a really good job at this, and u don't have to have the src code downloaded to be searched)

Otherwise it's fun to use yt-dl, thanks for them!